# How to get the soap or http request object from a wcf class

Tags: wcf

From a wcf4 service need to access to the underlying http request,including it's soap message, how can I do that from code?, I know I can use fiddler, etc, but need to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).